# obtener la fecha y hora de un archivo y cuando haya una modificación en el archivo con la hora y fecha enviarlo al servidor

Tags: java, archivo, eventos

Tengo un archivo en un cliente ejemplo:

```
configuracion.txt
```

necesito hacer que se envié ese mismo archivo cuando alguien lo modifique .

ya tengo la fecha y hora en que se realizó la modificación.

pero no se como compararlo con la fecha anterior  y así poder enviarlo al servidor. espero este mas claro

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta carece de la informacion necesaria para que alguno de nosotros pueda ayudarte. Por favor consulta la [ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorarla.

Comment: me gustaría ver tu código completo con lo que solucionaste tu problema, un saludo!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola te genere un codigo a modo de ejemplo, te lo dejo a continuacion :

```
public static long tiempoDeModificacion = 234234234234L; //esta variable almacenara el de la ultima modificacion de tu archivo

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(); // generamos un ScheduledExecutorService para repetir una tarea en un tiempo constante
        //La tarea la guardaremos en una variable del tipo Runnable
        Runnable task = () -> {
                                    try
                                    {

                                        Path path = Paths.get("/home/charbel/Escritorio/wena.txt");//esta es la ruta de tu archivo en mi caso estoy utilizando GNU/Linux
                                        if(Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toMillis() != tiempoDeModificacion)//validamos que la ultima fecha de modificacion es distinta de la fecha que tenemos guardada
                                        {
                                            System.out.println("la fecha de modificacion cambio");
                                            tiempoDeModificacion = Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toMillis();//de ser verdadero debemos modificar nuestra variable para no caer en un ciclo infinito
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            System.out.println("el archivo no ha cambiado");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch(Exception e)
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("algo mal sucedio");
                                    }
                              };
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//damos inicio a la tarea con un defase inicial de 0 y con un intervalo de 5 Segundos

    }
```

Espero te sirva

Saludos.

Comment: Hola @Jose Felipe Charbel ! de verdad muchas gracias ! me ayudaste como no tienes idea! , soy un principiante en este mundo de la programación estoy poniendo de todo mi empeño para aprender lo mas que pueda! y con personas como tu que apoyan la verdad es mucho mejor ! , adapte el ´código´ que me proporcionaste y funciono a la perfección en  lo que estoy desarrollando. De antemano muchas gracias ! Saludos!

Comment: Estimado , saber que pude ayudar me hace feliz enormemente , muchas gracias por tu comentario y te seguire ayudando